# Is there a way to tell what kind of MAC header a packet is using?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, network-protocols, wifi

Is there a way to check what kind of MAC header a packet has in the kernel (ie. 802.11 or 802.2), either by looking at the packet itself (the headers) or by using some interface in the system?

Comment: Isn't the EtherType field in the frame made for that purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by the EtherType field? In 802.11 there is only a 2-bit field inside the Frame Control field that tells you what kind of 802.11 packet it is. 802.3 has a length/type field or simply length field. None of the two kinds of mac headers have a definite "type" field in a fixed place that tell you what kind of mac header it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Linux Kernel v3.6.1, `include/linux/ieee80211.h` there seems to be a function that detects whether the Ethernet frame is of type IEEE802.11.

There you go:

```
/**
 * ieee80211_is_data_present - check if type is IEEE80211_FTYPE_DATA and has data
 * @fc: frame control bytes in little-endian byteorder
 */
static inline int ieee80211_is_data_present(__le16 fc)
{
        /*
         * mask with 0x40 and test that that bit is clear to only return true
         * for the data-containing substypes.
         */
        return (fc & cpu_to_le16(IEEE80211_FCTL_FTYPE | 0x40)) ==
               cpu_to_le16(IEEE80211_FTYPE_DATA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The kernel receives the MAC headers, so in the kernel, yes, there is a way of looking at the MAC headers.

In userspace, it's more complex. You won't be passed the MAC headers for an IP packet to a normal TCP connection socket (for instance). However, you can process connections using (e.g.) `ebtables` and `iptables`. From there you can mark the connections (with `--connmark`), and you could find the appropriate connection with `libconntrack` or similar, and read the mark off. You could use this technique to distinguish between two categories of mac header.

So how to achieve this depends on what you want to do.

Comment: you can look at the MAC headers in the kernel, yes, but is there a way to tell what kind of MAC header it is? Because depending on whether it's 802.11 or 802.3, the destination mac address is at different places